# PHP MySQL mandatory field

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this query

```
$tww_update_sql = "UPDATE `telesales_anc` SET
`Ime` = '".$_POST['Ime'];
```

and I have a form with submit button as follows:

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="ANC_pozivanje_test.php">                                                                       
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
<small>Ime</small>
<input id="contact_name" type="text" name="Ime" placeholder="Ime" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $values['Ime']?>">
</div>                                                                      
<div class="form-group">
<div id="contact_submit" class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
<button  type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">Save</button>   
</div>  
</div>
```

Script that I used for checking in field is populated is as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        <!-- Real-time Validation -->
            <!--Name can't be blank-->
            $('#contact_name').on('input', function() {
                var input=$(this);
                var is_name=input.val();
                if(is_name){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
                else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
            });

        <!-- After Form Submitted Validation-->
            $("#contact_submit button").click(function(event){
                var form_data=$("#contact_name").serializeArray();
                var error_free=true;
                for (var input in form_data){
                    var element=$("#contact_name"+form_data[input]['']);
                    var valid=element.hasClass("valid");
                    var error_element=$("span", element.parent());
                    if (!valid){
                       error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show");
                       error_free=false;
                    }                                        
                    else{                   
                       error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");
                    }
               }
               if (!error_free){
                   event.preventDefault(); 
               }
               else{
                   alert('Status nije popunjen');
               }
          });           
    });
</script>
```

Problem is when button is submitted (if field is not populated) I got message "Status nije popunjen" but form is submited regard message.

Is it necessary to use script for this?

Comment: Try return false

Answer (score 0):

It seems you check whether `error_free` is false, in which case you prevent for submission, however, if it is true (so if the field is populated), you only give an alert. Shouldn't `event.preventDefault()` be inside else?

Comment: I try put `event.preventDefault()` inside else statement but now got a message if the field is populated or not. And submit does not work

Answer (score 0):

You should not listen to button.click, but to form.submit.

```
<!-- After Form Submitted Validation-->
$("#contact").on('submit', function(event) {
```

The method `event.preventDefault()` will prevent the form from submitting, and should be in the same block as the alert()

```
if (!error_free) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Status nije popunjen');
}
```

Comment: Try this, but now form is just submitted regarding the field input

Answer (score 0):

all you want to do is to validate the data on the client side, making sure that a valid name is supplied. i will recreate this here.

You can simply make changes to it. but i believe this solves your need. Also note that you should validate data on the server. dont just rely on client side validation

```
$update_sql = "UPDATE " . $table_name . " SET Ime = '" . $_POST['txt-name'] . "'";
```

```js
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function() {
    //bind click event on the button
    var form = document.forms['frm-contact'];
    $('#btn-contact').bind('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //this will prevent the form from getting submitted, so that we can validate the user name.
        var field = form.elements['txt-name'],
        name = field.value,
        len = name.length,
        error = '';
        if (len === 0) {
          error = 'Enter your name';
        }
        else if (len < 2) {
            error = 'name should not be less than 2 characters';
        }
        else if (len > 36) {
            error = 'name should not exceed 36 characters';
        }
        else if (/^[^a-z]+/i.test(name)) {
            error = 'name must start with letters';
        }
        else if (!/^['.a-z\- ]+$/i.test(name)) {
           error = 'invalid characters found'; // name should contain only alphabets, dash character, space character and dot character only
        }
        
        //done validating. show error now or submit the form.
        if (error) {
            alert(error);
            $(field).addClass('error');
        }
        else {
            $(field).removeClass('error');
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.error {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="frm-contact" id="frm-contact" method="post" action="example.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txt-name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="txt-name" id="txt-name" placeholder="enter your name" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btn-contact" id="btn-contact" value="contact us">SEND</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i see this is working on snipper (here on the page) but on my local.php won't :(
I copy all code into script and replace ID's of your form to my

Comment: the front end code i wrote above is working well. it is your backend php that is giving error.  Try this for the update statement    $tww_update_sql = "UPDATE `telesales_anc` SET
`Ime` = '" . $_POST['txt-name'] . "'";                note that i completed a single quote you omitted